# How to make TextBox fill all available space without later resizing to its content?

Tags: wpf, textbox, user-controls, grid

I have the following `Grid` with a `TextBox` in it:

```
<UserControl ...>
 <Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="30px"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition Height="1px"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" AcceptsReturn="True"
   TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
   VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
  <!-- content in other cells of the Grid's first column -->
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want the `TextBox` to fill all space that is available on the control (width and height-wise) and should the user enter more text than fits into it I want its vertical scrollbar to become active, without resizing the `TextBox`. What happens instead is that the size of the `TextBox` changes to accomodate the content and the whole grid grows with it.

How do I achieve what I need?

**Edit:** Here's an illustration of what happens.
[image: Two screenshots of the same <code>UserControl</code> with different content in <code>TextBox</code>.]

The above screenshot is of the situation when the content fits comfortably into the `TextBox`. The below screenshot is of the situation when there is not enough room to fit all content - the `TextBox` is then resized to fit it and this resizes also the grid that it is placed in, making it look broken.

**Edit 2:** The project that demonstrates this behavior is [here](https://github.com/ReasonSharp/SO_LocationViewer).

Comment: just set one of rows height to star `*`

Comment: @Mikolaytis that doesn't work, see my reply to mm8's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by adding an invisible `Border` in the same cells of the `Grid` as the `TextBox`, then setting `TextBox`' `Width` and `Height` to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of that `Border` respectively:

```
<Border x:Name="b" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"
 Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b}"
 Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=b}"
 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

This then caused the `TextBox` to stay of fixed `Height` regardless of its content, but there was another problem with its `Width`: it grew when the interface was expanded, but didn't shrink afterwards, because of the underlying `ScrollViewer`. The trick was to set that `ScrollViewer`'s `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled`, instead of `Hidden` as I had done previously.

I pushed changes of the example project to GitHub, so the solution is now available [here](https://github.com/ReasonSharp/SO_LocationViewer).

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` doesn't fill the `Grid`. You can confirm this yourself by specifying a `Background` for the `Grid`:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
    ...
```

This is because the height of the `Grid` is 30 px + whatever the height of the `TextBox` is + 1 px. For the contents of the row 2 or 3 to fill the `Grid`, you need to change the `Height` of at least one of the `RowDefinitions` to `*`:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Background="Yellow">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30px"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1px"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" AcceptsReturn="True"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The 1px row is intentional and no controls are to be placed there. As for using the * on rows 2 or 3, this still doesn't solve the problem. As `TextBox` gets resized, the height of the first row is changed. If I set `MaxHeight="30px"` to row 1 then second row is resized. No matter how I place asterisks (row 2 only, 3 only, or both), the result is the same. The key, I think, would be to prevent the `TextBox` from sizing to content and make it size to fill its container (that is grid column 2, rows 1, 2 and 3) as is the case when there is no content, or content fits its initial size.

Comment: Did you try my sample markup? It works as expected for me. It can't "size to fill its container" unless the container has some kind of constrained size.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Which version of .NET are you using? I'm on 4.5.2 and I tried switching to 4.6.2 without effect. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by the container needing to have a constrained size. It does have a constrained size, and it is a derivative to the size of the `UserControl` it is placed in. And initially, the `TextBox` *does* size correctly to fit the cells I mentioned. The problem is when there is entered text, then the `TextBox` gets resized to fit content, rather than remain the size it initially was. That is a weird default behavior.

Comment: So the TextBox gets smaller when you enter text in or what do you mean? Does it grow?

Comment: it stays the same size until the content no longer fits. Then it grows with the content. I'm going to make some screenshots so it's easier for you to see.

Comment: And just to be clear, you are trying the exact same code I posted now? What's the parent element of the UserControl?

Comment: The parent is a `StackPanel` containing multiple `UserControl`s such as I posted. It is in a `ScrollViewer` which is in a `Grid` of another `UserControl`. The snippet is the same, except I put more content in other cells of the grid (a `DataGrid` in column 1, row 3 and a number of labels organized in various panels in other rows).

Comment: I have expanded my question with the illustration.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible sample including the StackPanel and the ScrollViewer and everything else needed to reproduce your issue from scratch.

Comment: The minimal project is on GitHub: https://github.com/ReasonSharp/SO_LocationViewer